# No swapfile on Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: swap, 22.10

My fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.10 does not have a swapfile.
System Monitor shows "Swap not available".

(My previous installation of Ubuntu 22.04 did have a swapfile, and I did not have to do anything to set that up).

You can see I have 16GB of memory, form the screenshot below.

I also have 88GB of available disk space in the root partition.

Question: Does 22.10 no longer setup a swapfile during installation, or did something unusual happen on my system?

[image: System Monitor shows "Swap not available"]

Comment: Does `/etc/fstab` not show a line for a swap file? 

Comment: There is no swap file in `/etc/fstab`. I'm wondering if this is an issue with the 22.10 installer? In 22.04 I had a system created swap file.